# jQuery affect classes outside parent element

Tags: jquery, class, parent

Is there a jQuery function to select all DOM elements of a certain class that are *outside* the parent(s) of an element selected with `$(this)`?

Thanks,

James

Comment: By parents. do you mean _all_ the ancestors? Because _everything_ will be contained within an ancestor of any given element. Short of there being multiple document trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the ancestors (gotten via [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)), like this:

```
$(".class").not($(this).parents())
```

Comment: Thank you :-) this works perfectly. +1 for uber simple answer!